# Is there a method to find a vector that optimizes a Rayleigh quotient over a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Let $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be an arbitary Hermitian matrix and let $E$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Is there a method to find vectors $y,z\in E$ such that
$$\dfrac{y^*My}{y^*y}=\sup_{x\in E\\
x\neq0}\dfrac{x^*Mx}{x^*x}\mbox{ and }\dfrac{z^*Mz}{z^*z}=\inf_{x\in E\\
x\neq0}\dfrac{x^*Mx}{x^*x}\hspace{3mm}?$$
If $E=\mathbb{C}^n$ then $x$ and $y$ will be any eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the largest and smallest eigenvalues of $M$ respectively, so the method to find them is standard. How to find $y$ and $z$ when $E$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\dim(E)>1$?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't choose a basis of $E$, write $M$ in that basis, and proceed according to standard methods?

Comment: @Neal could you please be a little more specific? I must be blind because I do not see a natural approach to this problem.

Comment: If you have a subspace then you can find a basis. What's the problem?

Comment: Pick a basis $e_i$ of $E$, let $N$ be the $\dim(E)\times\dim(E)$ matrix with $N_{ij} = M(e_i,e_j)$. Then extremize the Rayleigh quotient of $N$ over $E$. By construction this will yield the extremal values of the Rayleigh quotient of $M$ over $E$.